# NewBuffer([]bytes,int,int64) method not found in go lang bytes package

Tags: go

I'm new in go language. I'm trying to understand what's happening inside [ioutil](https://golang.org/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go?s=1147:1188#L31).ReadAll(r Reader, capacity int64) method. Inside this method there is a line like:

```
buf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, capacity))
```

But **the problem is inside bytes package there is a NewBuffer method with only parameter** like:

```
func NewBuffer(buf []byte) *Buffer
```

I searched [bytes](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/) package documentation again and again but can't find NewBuffer method with 3 parameter.

**So actually from where NewBuffer(make([]byte, int, int64)) method calling?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`make([]byte, 0, capacity)` returns a new byte slice (`[]byte`) initialized to length 0 and capacity `capacity`.

In other words, it might help you to see it on multiple lines:

```
capacity := 100 // or whatever
var myBytes []byte = make([]byte, 0, capacity)
buf := bytes.NewBuffer(myBytes)
```

Answer (score 2):

Youre missing the fact that you're calling the `bytes.NewBuffer()` function with a single parameter, which happens to be a method call - [`make([]byte, 0, capacity)`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels) - which returns an byte slice.

Comment: How stupid I am. Wasted 1 hour to figure out this simple thing. Thank you very much.